# How to close a browser window from R?

Tags: r, cran

I'm preparing an R package to submit to CRAN. One of the bullet points listed on the CRAN policies list is

> Packages should not start external software (such as PDF viewers or browsers) during examples or tests unless that specific instance of the software is explicitly closed afterwards.

My package is all about building HTML files and then opening them with `browseURL`. So naturally my examples open up some browser windows! So I'm worried about that affecting my CRAN review.

However, I have no idea how to close these windows afterwards. Is there a function that does this? Google isn't turning up anything. Is this even possible?

UPDATE: I've submitted to CRAN and gotten a request back to remove the \dontrun tags. So apparently that is not the desired approach. But now I've got no clue as to how to approach this differently. Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't people sometimes just comment out certain portions of examples or tests? For example, packages which require a Google API key just comment out the portions of their examples which require the use of the key. Maybe that's enough?

Comment: I suppose I could do that! I'd need to comment out every instance of every function in the package, though. That seems suboptimal.

Comment: Not ideal, but you can always close them using javascript. The shinys package lets you run arbitrary javascript.

Comment: Oof, yeah, I guess that's an option.

Comment: Closing via javascript isn't reliable (you can disable javascript).  Wrapping your examples in \dontrun is probably best. That's what I do in my docstring package: https://github.com/Dasonk/docstring/blob/master/R/docstring.R and a lot of users will have help files set to open in a browser so it's a very similar situation

Comment: You can also put them in `if(interactive()) { }` blocks:  these aren't run during checks, only if an interactive user requests the example.  I think CRAN accepts that...

Comment: Oh that seems like the fix Dason.

Comment: (a) When you submitted with `\dontrun` did you include a clear note explaining the reason? (b) Have you tried asking on `r-package-devel@r-project.org`? (What I could fine on r-package-devel [supports the `if(interactive())` idea](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2015q3/000410.html), though the use-case seems somewhat different.)

Comment: My first submission I explained it, but I didn't on resubmission, and that's when I got the comment. That may just explain it